# Mule Application deploy issue in Anypoint Studio

Tags: maven, pom.xml, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4

I am trying to run an imported Application in Anypoint Studio which works with a SAP connector, but it fails right after starting, it seems to be related to the pom.xml file, as additional info I've been told that this project has been migrated from Mule 3 to Mule 4.
I get the following Output:

```
` 

[INFO] Scanning for projects... Downloading from jfrog: http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/plugins-releases-local/org/jfrog/maven/annomojo/maven-plugin-tools-anno/1.4.0/maven-plugin-tools-anno-1.4.0.pom 
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs: 
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: net.inspira.api:api-transformers:jar -> duplicate declaration of version 2.0.0 @ line 624, column 14 
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:1.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:jar:1.1 -> org.jfrog.maven.annomojo:maven-plugin-tools-anno:jar:1.4.0 @  
[ERROR] Unknown packaging: mule @ line 8, column 13  @  
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1][ERROR]    
[ERROR]   The project com.mycompany:sap-api-supply:3.2.0 (/home/byranernesto/AnypointStudio/studio-workspace/Mule sap-api-supply-new Application/pom.xml) has 2 errors [ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:1.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:jar:1.1 -> org.jfrog.maven.annomojo:maven-plugin-tools-anno:jar:1.4.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.jfrog.maven.annomojo:maven-plugin-tools-anno:jar:1.4.0: Could not transfer artifact org.jfrog.maven.annomojo:maven-plugin-tools-anno:pom:1.4.0 from/to jfrog (http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/plugins-releases-local): transfer failed for http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/plugins-releases-local/org/jfrog/maven/annomojo/maven-plugin-tools-anno/1.4.0/maven-plugin-tools-anno-1.4.0.pom, status: 503 Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/plugins-releases-local/org/jfrog/maven/annomojo/maven-plugin-tools-anno/1.4.0/maven-plugin-tools-anno-1.4.0.pom -> [Help 2] 
[ERROR]     Unknown packaging: mule @ line 8, column 13 [ERROR]  
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR]  
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: 
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException 
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginManagerException
```

`

My pom.xml file:

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>sap-api-supply</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <packaging>mule</packaging>
    <name>Mule sap-api-supply Application</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <mule.version>3.9.5</mule.version>
        <mule.tools.version>1.1</mule.tools.version>
        <mule-transport-sap.version>3.0.0</mule-transport-sap.version>
        <sapjco.version>3.0.14</sapjco.version>
        <sapidoc.version>3.0.12</sapidoc.version>
        <lib.directory>${project.build.directory}/lib</lib.directory>
        <native.lib.directory>${lib.directory}/${envClassifier}</native.lib.directory>
    </properties>



    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dos-i386</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>windows</family>
                    <arch>i386</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>ntintel</envClassifier>
                <envType>dll</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>sapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>windows-i386</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>windows</family>
                    <arch>i386</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>ntintel</envClassifier>
                <envType>dll</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>sapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>dos-x86</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>dos</family>
                    <arch>x86</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>ntintel</envClassifier>
                <envType>dll</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>sapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>windows-x86</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>windows</family>
                    <arch>x86</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>ntintel</envClassifier>
                <envType>dll</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>sapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>dos-x86_64</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>dos</family>
                    <arch>x86_64</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>ntamd64</envClassifier>
                <envType>dll</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>sapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>windows-x86_64</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>windows</family>
                    <arch>x86_64</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>ntamd64</envClassifier>
                <envType>dll</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>sapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>dos-amd64</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>dos</family>
                    <arch>amd64</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>ntamd64</envClassifier>
                <envType>dll</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>sapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>windows-amd64</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>windows</family>
                    <arch>amd64</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>ntamd64</envClassifier>
                <envType>dll</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>sapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>linux-i386</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <name>linux</name>
                    <arch>i386</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>linuxintel</envClassifier>
                <envType>so</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>libsapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>linux-x86</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <name>linux</name>
                    <arch>x86</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>linuxintel</envClassifier>
                <envType>so</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>libsapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>linux-x86_64</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <name>linux</name>
                    <arch>x86_64</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>linuxx86_64</envClassifier>
                <envType>so</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>libsapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>linux-amd64</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <name>linux</name>
                    <arch>amd64</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>linuxx86_64</envClassifier>
                <envType>so</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>libsapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>macosx-i386</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <name>mac os x</name>
                    <arch>i386</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>darwinintel</envClassifier>
                <envType>jnilib</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>libsapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>macosx-x86</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <name>mac os x</name>
                    <arch>x86</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>darwinintel</envClassifier>
                <envType>jnilib</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>libsapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>macosx-x86_64</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <name>mac os x</name>
                    <arch>x86_64</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>darwinintel64</envClassifier>
                <envType>jnilib</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>libsapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>macosx-amd64</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <name>mac os x</name>
                    <arch>amd64</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>darwinintel64</envClassifier>
                <envType>jnilib</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>libsapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>studio</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>runtime</name>
                    <value>studio</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.7</source>
                            <target>1.7</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-native-lib-for-unit-tests</id>
                                <phase>process-sources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                                    <outputDirectory>${native.lib.directory}</outputDirectory>
                                    <artifactItems>
                                        <!-- We use maven profiles to choose the native library according 
                                        to architecture and operating system -->
                                        <artifactItem>
                                        <groupId>com.sap.conn.jco</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>sapjco3</artifactId>
                                        <type>${envType}</type>
                                        <classifier>${envClassifier}</classifier>
                                        <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                        <destFileName>${native.lib.filename}.${envType}</destFileName>
                                        </artifactItem>
                                        <!-- If the target platform differ from your development platform, 
                                        you can add the native library uncommenting the following block Note that 
                                        you must set the following elements accordingly: type, classifier, outputDirectory 
                                        and destFileName -->

                                        <artifactItem>
                                        <groupId>com.sap.conn.jco</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>sapjco3</artifactId>
                                        <type>so</type>
                                        <classifier>linuxx86_64</classifier>
                                        <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                        <outputDirectory>${lib.directory}/linuxx86_64</outputDirectory>
                                        <destFileName>libsapjco3.so</destFileName>
                                        </artifactItem>

                                    </artifactItems>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-jco-libs-unit-tests</id>
                                <phase>process-sources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                                    <outputDirectory>${lib.directory}</outputDirectory>
                                    <artifactItems>
                                        <artifactItem>
                                        <groupId>com.sap.conn.jco</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>sapjco3</artifactId>
                                        <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                        <destFileName>sapjco3.jar</destFileName>
                                        </artifactItem>
                                        <artifactItem>
                                        <groupId>com.sap.conn.idoc</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>sapidoc3</artifactId>
                                        <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                        <destFileName>sapidoc3.jar</destFileName>
                                        </artifactItem>
                                        <artifactItem>
                                        <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>mule-transport-sap</artifactId>
                                        <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                        <destFileName>mule-transport-sap-${mule-transport-sap.version}.jar</destFileName>
                                        </artifactItem>
                                    </artifactItems>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>add-sap-jars</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <target>
                                        <zip destfile="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.zip" update="true">
                                        <zipfileset dir="${project.build.directory}/lib" prefix="lib"/>
                                        </zip>
                                    </target>
                                </configuration>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                </plugins>
            </build>

        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.tools.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                     <sharedLibraries>
                                                <sharedLibrary>
                                                        <groupId>net.inspira.api</groupId>
                                                        <artifactId>api-transformers</artifactId>
                                                </sharedLibrary>
                                                <sharedLibrary>
                                                        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
                                                        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                    </sharedLibraries>
                    <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
                    <inclusions>
                        <inclusion>
                            <groupId>com.mulesoft.security</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mule-module-security-property-placeholder</artifactId>
                        </inclusion>
                        <inclusion>
                            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mule-transport-sap</artifactId>
                        </inclusion>
                    <inclusion>
                            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mule-module-apikit-soap</artifactId>
                        </inclusion>
<!--                         Cloud Areas -->
                    <inclusion>
                            <groupId>3284c114-3570-4feb-a444-7d90b56935a3</groupId>
                            <artifactId>basetis-sap-connector</artifactId>
                        </inclusion>
<!--                         Cloud Areas -->


<!--                         Cloud de Mule -->
<!--                     <inclusion> -->
<!--                             <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId> -->
<!--                             <artifactId>basetis-sap-connector</artifactId> -->
<!--                         </inclusion> -->
<!--                         Cloud de Mule -->
                   
                    </inclusions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>project</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-resource</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/app/</directory>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>mappings/</directory>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/api/</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- Mule Dependencies -->
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-core-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mule Transports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-file</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jdbc-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jms-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-vm</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mule Modules -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-scripting</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SAP Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-sap</artifactId>
            <version>${mule-transport-sap.version}</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.conn.jco</groupId>
            <artifactId>sapjco3</artifactId>
            <version>${sapjco.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.conn.idoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>sapidoc3</artifactId>
            <version>${sapidoc.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- for testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-apikit</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.weave</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-plugin-weave</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-json</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.inspira.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>api-internal-security</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>net.inspira.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>api-transformers</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.inspira.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>api-connection</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-security-property-placeholder</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-apikit-soap</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
                  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
<!--     Cloud Areas -->
     <dependency>
  <groupId>3284c114-3570-4feb-a444-7d90b56935a3</groupId>
  <artifactId>basetis-sap-connector</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.5</version>

</dependency>
<!--     Cloud Areas -->

<!--     Cloud Mule -->
<!--     <dependency> -->
<!--             <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId> -->
<!--             <artifactId>basetis-sap-connector</artifactId> -->
<!--             <version>1.1.1</version> -->
<!--         </dependency> -->
<!--     Cloud Mule -->

    
    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.inspira.api</groupId>
                        <artifactId>api-transformers</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.0</version>
                </dependency>
<dependency>
                        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
                        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.1</version>
                </dependency>

</dependencies>

    <repositories>
<!--    Repository Areas -->
    <repository>
    <id>Repository</id>
    <name>Exchange Repository</name>
    <url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v1/organizations/3284c114-3570-4feb-a444-7d90b56935a3/maven</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
  </repository>
  <!--  Repository Areas -->
        <repository>
            <id>Central</id>
            <name>Central</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    <repository>
            <id>anypoint-exchange</id>
            <name>Exchange Repository</name>
            <url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v1/organizations/3284c114-3570-4feb-a444-7d90b56935a3/maven</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>mulesoft-release</id>
            <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>



</project>
```

`

I tried to fix it by adding the dependencies with the "<sharedLibraries>" tag in the pom.xml file but seems it didn't work, I dont know what else to try, I would apreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a POM for a Mule 3 application. It will never work to build a Mule 4 application and Anypoint Studio 7.x (the version compatible with Mule 4 projects) will not be able to import it. Either you have an incorrect version or it is not really migrated. You need to create a pom.xml for a Mule 4 application. Since this is a complex POM it may not be trivial. And that is not counting any possible pending migration of the application itself.

Note that `<sharedLibraries>` is used to solve classloading issues at execution time. It build not help with the build at all.

Comment: Thank you I will try to use a lower version of Anypoint since I was just told that specially this Application had to be run in Mule 3

Comment: The pom is for Mule 3. You should use the latest Anypoint Studio 6.x available. I meant it is not migrated to Mule 4.